# How to check how many External Hard Drives are connected to Linux Server

Tags: rhel, removable-storage

Is there a way to distinguish between the Internal Hard drives and External Hard drives.

Actually i need to see how many External hardrives do we have and to which server are they connected .

This is the Screenshot i took and by judging by its name SDE is external hard drive. But im not sure .

So help me out.

[image]

### Further actions

Ok now i used lsusb and it said Western Digital Drive connected and its Drive No is SDE. But by using dmesg it said that sdb is also a removable disk. Any suggestions

```
'sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi removable disk sdb
  Vendor: WDC       Model: WD2500YD-01NVB1   Rev: 10.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
  Vendor: WDC       Model: WD2500YD-01NVB1   Rev: 10.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
  Vendor: WDC       Model: WD2500YD-01NVB1   Rev: 10.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
  Vendor: WDC       Model: WD2500YD-01NVB1   Rev: 10.0
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
```

Comment: (offtopic) Please don't use screenshots if you don't have to. You could just copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@umair i am not sure why sdb is showing as removable , could you post the o/p of this script

```
for device in /sys/block/*
do
    if udevadm info --query=property --path=$device | grep -q ^ID_BUS=usb
    then
        echo $device
    fi
done
```

Comment: Well the hard disk is already mounted and dmesg gives some 4 page output I didnt find this command helpful.

Comment: @Umair lsusb this command will list all information about USB buses and devices that are attached to them, just see whether it helps

Comment: Dear I used lsusb and added the detail in Question under Further actions. Kindly check it.

Comment: `sdb` is marked as removable, probably because the controller supports SCSI/SATA hotplugging - also called "hot swap".

Answer (score 1):

I like to use this one-liner.

```
find /dev/disk/by-path -name "*-usb-*" -not -name "*-part*" -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

It will 1) list all devices with USB in its path somewhere, 2) filters for partitions and finally 3) reads the link it points to. Example output:

```
/dev/sdc
```

Important notes:

- It will not work for external disks connected using another bus, e.g. eSATA, firewire, etc.
- It's not able to distinguish USB flash drives and regular spinning hard drives.

Comment: Means it will also list the devices like mouse, Keyboard???

Comment: @UmairMustafa No. See the find path: `/dev/disk`.